# How to get sharedPreferences from repository

Tags: android

I have my own sharedPreference.

```
object MyPreferences {

    fun getStoredArg(context: Context): String {
        val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
        return prefs.getString(PREF_ARG, "testExample")!!
    }
}
```

And I have one repository that I want to get this sharedPreferences value.

```
class MyRepository(private val database: MyDatabase, application: Application) {

    val pref_arg: String
        get() = MyPreferences.getStoredArg(application) // but I cannot get the application context here, how should I fix it?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `application` argument as a class property using `val application`:

```
class MyRepository(private val database: MyDatabase, val application: Application) 
...
```

Or if you want to avoid storing the reference to the application context in your `MyRepository` class re-declare your `pref_arg` variable as:

```
val pref_arg: String = MyPreferences.getStoredArg(application)
```